# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when reading a file

Tags: c

I want to write a C program that can read this file containing a 3x3 matrix

```
 1 2 3 
 4 5 6
 2 8 7
```

but I get: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;
    int i, j;
    int mat[2][2];

    if (argc != 1) {
        if((fp = fopen(*++argv, "r")) == NULL) {
            printf("I can't open file %s\n", *argv);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for(i=0,j=0; i < 3; i++, j++)
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &mat[i][j]);

    printf("%d",mat[2][2]);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int mat[2][2];` -->`int mat[3][3];` Also you are only reading the first 3 numbers into diagonal position.

Comment: @kiranBiradar this can be detailled in an answer

Comment: And, you will read into the diagonal only. You need a pair of nested loops, or read in 3 values in each loop.

Comment: Aside: in `fopen(*++argv, "r")` it is not the best idea to increment a function argument. `fopen(argv[1], "r")` would be better, and clearer.

Comment: And with the `printf"%d", mat[2][2]);`, you are trying to access out of bound if your array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems.

1. First problem.

   ```
   int mat[2][2];
   ```

   Is `2*2` matrix with indexes `[0,1]`.
   You need.

   ```
   int mat[3][3];
   ```
2. As of now you are reading first 3 numbers into diagonal positions.
   What you need is

   ```
   for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
       for(j=0; j < 3; j++)
           fscanf(fp, "%d", &mat[i][j]);
   ```

Comment: Yep, if `argc == 1`